# BehaviorTree for high level logic

Tags: ros2, ros-humble

I want to use BehaviorTrees for my robot high level tasks. I found many hints on Nav2 plugins but this is not what I'm looking for.

Lets imagine a vacuum cleaner. Beside nav2 stuff, robot needs to do some more general tasks.

I.e. in most cases, it will be at charging station. Here, it is either charging or idle. When you start, it will do some undocking procedure. After that, it will start cleaning. While cleaning, it might trigger its bumper and start recovery. If battery gets drawn empty, robot must go back close to charge station. Then it must dock.

To my understanding, all this are states or leaves of a BT. What I don't understand is, how are data of robot (sensor data) handled between the states? I heared the name  blackboard, but didn't understand it. Do subscribed topics influence the BT? I mean, while cleaning we receive a low battery message. In this case, we must switch to a different state.

As you see, I'm looking for more general information. What I've found are instructions on how to create plugins for nav2 bt with some deep dive but I don't understand it.

Is there some more general example or guidance on how to use BT for use case I described above?

Patrick

Comment: I'd recommend by starting with learning about BTs in general: An Introduction to Behavior Trees for Robotics and AI is a free PDF and does a great job in the first few chapters.

Comment: Thank you @SteveMacenski, I've read the document you mentioned. It is really valuable and well written. Now I've got a better understanding. But it doesn't show how to integrate with ros2. To my understanding, the nodes of BT needs to know status of robot and data of topics. These must be stored, maybe in a dedicated ros2 node holding all data and manage topics. BT itself then might only call Services and Action provided by ros2 robot node. Is that right? Any examples available?